# Global Leaflet Map in R - issues adding data to spatial object

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to replicate this visual, but with my own data. This is the template I am working off of - https://r-graph-gallery.com/183-choropleth-map-with-leaflet.html

My intent is to highlight every country with a value in the same color. I might make it a heatmap or something - but right now adding the polygons gives an error so I cannot try any color options at all.

```
# Setup
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(here)
library(tidyverse)

# Basically copy pasted from the template, but the download did not work. I manually went to the website, downloaded the file, manually un-zipped, and manually dropped it in my working directory
# download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip" , destfile="DATA/world_shape_file.zip")
# system("unzip DATA/world_shape_file.zip")
world_spdf <- readOGR( 
  dsn= here() , 
  layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3",
  verbose=FALSE
)

world_spdf@data$POP2005[ which(world_spdf@data$POP2005 == 0)] = NA
world_spdf@data$POP2005 <- as.numeric(as.character(world_spdf@data$POP2005)) / 1000000 %>% round(2)

# Example of my data - I have countries and numbers associated with them, although not every country has a number

country <- c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia")
values <- c(1,4,4)

my_df <- dataframe(country, values)

# This is how I am trying to add MY values to the map. I have to convert the map to a tibble, add my data, then convert it back to a map. Perhaps this is the problem? 
interactive_data_attempt <- world_spdf %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  left_join(my_df , by = c("NAME" = "country")) %>% 
  mutate(texts = replace_na(texts, 0),
         exists = texts > 1) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LON","LAT"))

# This is the method I used to do the exact same thing in a domestic US map
bins <- c(seq(0,1,1), Inf)
pal <- colorBin(c("white","#C14A36"), domain = interactive_data_attempt$exists, bins = bins, reverse = FALSE)

# This gives an error: Error in to_ring.default(x) : Don't know how to get polygon data from object of class XY,POINT,sfg
leaflet(interactive_data_attempt) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lat=10, lng=0 , zoom=2) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(interactive_data_attempt$exists))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `readOGR` to get an sp object, but at one point you convert it to tibble and then to sf? Not sure about sp, but in most cases you can handle sf as a regular tibble / dataframe, i.e. `left_join`to it. And you can read shapefile directly to sf with `st_read`.

Then there's something with your variables, a mixup from copy-paste I would guess: in `my_df` you have `values` but you never do anything with it and in your `mutate` you use `texts` but it's unclear where it's coming from.

Binary palette is built from `exists`, a boolean value that should indicate if the actual value is present or not, though I'd assume you'd want to use values from your `my_df$values` instead.

Left NA values as-is, changed bins (to just 2) and adjusted some colours.

```r
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# download.file("http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip" , destfile="world_shape_file.zip")
# unzip("world_shape_file.zip",exdir = "world_shape_file")
world_sf <- st_read("world_shape_file")

world_sf$POP2005[ which(world_sf$POP2005 == 0)] = NA
world_sf$POP2005 <- as.numeric(as.character(world_sf$POP2005)) / 1000000 %>% round(2)

country <- c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia")
values <- c(1,4,4)

pal <- colorBin(c("blue","#C14A36"), domain = values, bins = 2, reverse = FALSE, na.color = "transparent")

world_sf %>% 
  left_join(
    tibble(country, values), 
    by = c("NAME" = "country")) %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lat=10, lng=0 , zoom=2) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(values), stroke = FALSE)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>